# Steps to merge original tree into result tree

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, tree

Having **original** and "final"/**result** tree. I want to compare these **trees** and "reproduce" the steps, which would be carried to have same results.

**Real-life example:** Having original tree in the database. A worker has prepared changes (generate new result tree in App) and now we need to update the database. We are unable to drop database and reupload, as there might be data which haven't been generated.

Class/Table definition:

```
class TreeNode
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public TreeNode Parent { get; set; }

    /* some other properties */
}
```

Example trees:

```
Origin                         Result
|A                              |A
| -1                            | -2
| -2                            |C
|B                              | -3
| -5                            |D
|  --£                          | -1
|C                              |  --£
|F                              | -5
| -7                            |E
|H                              | -6
                                |G
                                | -4
                                |H
```

What I expect is to have an algorithm, via which I will be allowed to handle when the objects are **added**, **deleted** or **moved**.

> IMPORTANT: The objects that have other parent should not be **removed** and **added** back, instead they should be only **moved** under other parent! Remove would cause data loss.

Example:

```
Mark B as removed
Mark F as removed
Add D
Add E
Add G
Move 1 under D
Move 5 under D
Mark 7 as removed
Add 3 under C
Add 6 under E
Add 4 under G
Move £ under 1
Removed 7
Removed F
Removed B
```

---

**Own solution**

I created sample with **Win-Forms** and **TreeView**. My algorithm work only per-level base (e.g. move 1 from A to D), but not across. Elements are first market as to be deleted, removed at the end.

[image: Application screenshot]

Code:

```
//Recursive loop to find all nodes in Nth level
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> getNodesOnLevel(TreeNodeCollection aCollection, int aLevel)
{
    var lResultTreeNodeCol = new List<TreeNode>();

    if (aLevel == 1)
        return aCollection.Cast<TreeNode>();

    foreach(TreeNode nNode in aCollection)
    {
        lResultTreeNodeCol.AddRange(getNodesOnLevel(nNode.Nodes, aLevel - 1));
    }

    return lResultTreeNodeCol;
}

//Called once
public void UpdateTrees(TreeNodeCollection aCollectionA, TreeNodeCollection aCollectionB)
{
    List<TreeNode> lRemoved = new List<TreeNode>();
    for (int i = 1; UpdateWithLevel(aCollectionA, aCollectionB, i, ref lRemoved) > 0; i++)
    {
    }
    var lRem = lRemoved.LastOrDefault();
    do
    {
        W($"Removed {lRem.Text}");
        lRemoved.Remove(lRem);
    } while ((lRem = lRemoved.LastOrDefault()) != null);

}

//Called per level
private int UpdateWithLevel(TreeNodeCollection aCollectionA, TreeNodeCollection aCollectionB, int level, ref List<TreeNode> aRemoved)
{
    int lNumOfUpdates = 0;
    var colA = getNodesOnLevel(aCollectionA, level);
    var colB = getNodesOnLevel(aCollectionB, level);

    //Search Original collection, compare to Result collection
    foreach (TreeNode nodeA in colA)
    {
        //Find nodeA in Result collection
        var lNodeAinColB = colB.FirstOrDefault((a) => a.Text == nodeA.Text);

        if(lNodeAinColB == null) //NodeA not found in result collection - delete
        {
            aRemoved.Add(nodeA);
            W($"Mark {nodeA.Text} as removed");
            lNumOfUpdates++;
        }
        else if((lNodeAinColB.Parent?.Text ?? "") != (nodeA.Parent?.Text ?? "")) //NodeA exists in Result collection, different parrent -> must be moved
        {
            W($"Move {nodeA.Text} under {lNodeAinColB.Parent.Text}");
            lNumOfUpdates++;
        }
    }

    //Search Result collection, if Original collection does not have nodeB, we must create it (add)
    foreach (TreeNode nodeB in colB)
    {
        if (!colA.Contains(nodeB, new TestNodeEquality()))
        {
            W($"Add {nodeB.Text}" + ((nodeB.Parent != null)?$" under {nodeB.Parent.Text}":""));
            lNumOfUpdates++;
        }
    }

    return lNumOfUpdates;
}
```

I haven't found any topics that fits my problem nor valuable resources & I would really like to avoid reinventing wheel.

**Question(s):**

- Is there existing & working alghoritm (name/reference)? What is this kind of alghorithms/actions called (Tree Diff/Merge/Lookup/..)?
- Can I optimize the alghoritm in any way?

Comment: @jdweng Could You please point me to direct article?

Comment: If each node has an unique identity, you could easily compare their state changes node-by-node disregarding levels, then apply the changes, I suppose?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_sort
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

Comment: @jdweng - I'm afraid these links/articles are about binary trees, not the multi-leaf causes.

Comment: @AKX That actually make sense, I was thinking about this implementation also. I don't even see any downsides for this at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need some complex recursive algorithm here. Simply put your result nodes to the name-parent dictionary and check:

- whether the original node is in the dictionary
- whether the parent of original node changed
- whether there are nodes in the result which not exist in original nodes

Dictionary also provides O(1) for searching nodes, so that will be an optimization too. Same relates to `Except` operation, which is fast set operation.

Code:

```
var originalNodes = new List<TreeNode>(); // TreeNodeCollection 
var nodes = new List<TreeNode>();         // TreeNodeCollection 
var parentByName = nodes.ToDictionary(n => n.Text, n => n.Parent);

foreach(var originalNode in originalNodes)
{
    TreeNode parent;
    if (!parentByName.TryGetValue(originalNode.Text, out parent))
    {
        // removed - there is no key for original node name
        continue;
    }

    if (originalNode.Parent?.Text != parent?.Text)
    {
        // moved from originalNode.Parent to parent
        continue;
    }
}

// these guys are added
var added = parentByName.Keys.Except(originalNodes.Select(n => n.Text))
```

Comment: Simple and powerful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C# environment around, so I figured I could implement this in Python – they call it executable pseudocode, right? ;)

```
def node(id, children=[]):
    assert all(isinstance(child, dict) for child in children)
    return {'id': id, 'children': children}

tree1 = [
    node('a', [
        node('1'),
        node('2'),
    ]),
    node('b', [
        node('5', [
            node('*'),
        ]),
    ]),
    node('c'),
    node('f', [
        node('7'),
    ]),
    node('h'),
]


tree2 = [
    node('a', [
        node('2'),
    ]),
    node('c', [
        node('3'),
    ]),
    node('d', [
        node('1', [
            node('*'),
        ]),
        node('5'),
    ]),
    node('e', [
        node('6'),
    ]), 
    node('g', [
        node('4'),
    ]),
    node('h'),
]

def walk(tree, fn, parent=None):
    for node in tree:
        fn(node, parent)
        walk(node.get('children', ()), fn, parent=node)


def get_all_nodes_and_parents(tree):
    nodes = {}
    parents = {}
    def add_node(node, parent):
        nodes[node['id']] = node
        parents[node['id']] = (parent['id'] if parent else None)
    walk(tree, add_node)
    return (nodes, parents)


def treediff(t1, t2):
    n1, p1 = get_all_nodes_and_parents(t1)
    n2, p2 = get_all_nodes_and_parents(t2)
    new_nodes = set(n2.keys()) - set(n1.keys())
    del_nodes = set(n1.keys()) - set(n2.keys())

    for node_id in sorted(new_nodes):
        yield 'create node %s' % node_id

    for node_id in sorted(del_nodes):
        yield 'delete node %s' % node_id

    for node_id in n2:
        if p1.get(node_id) != p2.get(node_id):
            yield 'move node %s from %s to %s' % (node_id, p1.get(node_id), p2.get(node_id))

for op in treediff(tree1, tree2):
    print(op)
```

This outputs

```
create node 3
create node 4
create node 6
create node d
create node e
create node g
delete node 7
delete node b
delete node f
move node 3 from None to c
move node 1 from a to d
move node * from 5 to 1
move node 5 from b to d
move node 6 from None to e
move node 4 from None to g
```

A further improvement would be to create the new nodes directly under their new parents, but that will require the added complexity keeping track of the creation order, so parents are created before their new children.

Comment: Sergey made it much more simplier without recursion etc. However I'm glad for other language solution, appreciate!

Comment: Sure, recursion is not needed if the tree has an API to get all nodes regardless of their depth (and if they provide parent attributes) :)